Deeply understanding Volatile and Memory Barriers
I have been reading a ton on this topic over the past view days but would really like clarification on what I learned so far in relations to C# and C. Firstly, Atomicity seems to be fairly intrinsic in modern times where I am strictly referring to the ability to read and write within a single instruction. It seems that C# always naturally aligns its data (which also seems to be done in C as well, but I heard there's some cases this is not true). By alignment I mean that for example in x64 a long will be 8 bytes meaning its virtual memory address will be a multiple of 8. This way the CPU can read and write with its 8-byte wide BUS in a single cycle. If, however we were not aligned correctly and were off by a byte the CPU may require 2 cycles to read and write data which not only slows our program down it also removes atomicity since this could cause partial data to be observed. It's also good to mention that this seems to also work for other data like a 4-byte int where that can also be read and written to within a single cycle also making it atomic. Lastly, this also seems to yield extra optimization where when doing something like reading an array we can now read / write 2 int's at a time in our 8-byte wide BUS.
Now volatile in C# seems to do 2 things. Firstly, it prevents the CPU from storing copies of that data in its registers. It however, does not prevent the CPU from storing copies in its caches like L1, L2, or L3. Secondly, it provides a Memory Barrier which I will talk about in the next paragraph. Now in C it seems that volatile just prevents caching in registers without providing the memory barrier.
Continuing on a Memory Barrier seems to primarily prevent reordering of instructions. This is notable since modern CPU's do something called Speculative Execution which can lead to prematurely running code where if its guess was correct, we would have just of saved some time while if we guessed wrong, we can just roll back the changes. This however could cause problems if multiple threads are modifying data in a time sensitive manner. It's also worth to note that theres a read, write, and a full memory barrier where Thread.MemoryBarrier() in C# is a full memory barrier which means it works for both read and write instructions.
Of course, volatile and memory barriers are not a one size fit all solution it seems to be very useful when a single thread writes while other threads read. If multiple threads write to the data being protected by these measures, we can run into issues. Also, cache coherency is the reason why we can still cache this data in L1 - L3.
Question:
So now that I covered what I assume to be correct I am primarily confused about why we need a volatile signal flag in C# and why the C code looks so familiar to the C# code despite volatile in C not using a memory barrier by default. For example, in the following C# code if I were to remove the isDataReady signal flag I assume this code would still work fine with the only issue being the possibility of stale copies being in the CPU registers for a max of a few milliseconds. This would probably be fine if my specific use case had a tolerance of a few milliseconds but how does adding the volatile signal flag fix that exactly?
class ProducerConsumerExample
{
    private int[] data = new int[10];
    private volatile bool isDataReady = false;

    public void Producer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = i;  
        }

        Thread.MemoryBarrier();  // We need a memory barrier after we write
        isDataReady = true;      
    }

    public void Consumer()
    {
        while (!isDataReady)    
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);    
        }

        Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // We need a memory barrier before we read

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data[i]);  
        }
    }
}

Now in C I was told the use of memory barrier works the same even though in this case the volatile flag will not use a memory barrier behind the scenes. Does this mean in C if I wanted to just use a normal flag (not related to this example) I should also use a volatile field along with a memory barrier for read and write essentially making it work similar to a volatile field in C#? Furthermore, in the following C example I was given why does it look so similar to the C# example with the same use of volatile signal fields despite these signal fields not being protected by a memory barrier. Lastly, in both examples how does this volatile signal flag even help at all since I assume the array that is being looped over can still be copied in the CPU's registers.
#include <stdatomic.h>

volatile int isDataReady = 0;
int data[10];

void producer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data[i] = i;  
    }
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);  
    isDataReady = 1;  
}

void consumer() {
    while (isDataReady == 0) {
        
    }
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);  
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        process(data[i]);  
    }
}


Firstly, it prevents the CPU from storing copies of that data in its registers - It prevents the compiler from reusing a value from a register instead of accessing (cache coherent) shared memory again.  There will be copies of the value in CPU registers when you do something like int x = 2 * shared;, but the next read of shared won't assume it has the same value as before.  I assume that's what you meant, but your statement of it could be more precise.

Re: hardware atomicity guarantees, see Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86? for the x86 rules.  Yes, 8-byte aligned loads/stores are guaranteed atomic.  For cacheable memory regions, an external bus isn't the main factor, it's how the CPU core accesses its L1d cache, and how cache lines are transferred between cores.  AMD K10 could tear on 8-byte boundaries between sockets, but only on 16-byte boundaries between cores on the same chip. Intel guarantees atomicity for unaligned that doesn't split across cache lines.

Of course, these hardware atomicity guarantees aren't directly accessible from high-level languages; you need to know how something will compile.  Which is why in C you should #include <stdatomic.h> and use its functions, with memory_order_relaxed if you just wanted atomicity without ordering wrt. other accesses in the same thread. (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) -  When to use volatile with multi threading? - basically never in C or C++.

Using a separate barrier instead of an acquire load or release store is very inefficient on AArch64.  That ISA has instructions like ldapr for acquire load and stlr for release-store which just provide 1-way ordering for themselves, not a barrier for other loads/stores.  Also, your C technically has data-race undefined behaviour according to the ISO C standard.  Real compilers like GCC and clang do support using volatile to roll your own atomics, though, basically exposing the hardware guarantees of the target ISA.  But there's no reason to, except as a thought experiment.

if I were to remove the isDataReady signal flag I assume this code would still work fine with the only issue being the possibility of stale copies being in the CPU registers - Your code could then read the old values from cache/memory since the reader thread might get to its loop before the writer thread finished its loop and the stores became globally visible (by committing from the store buffer to cache).

If you loop repeatedly over the small array, the compiler might choose to reuse the values it read the first time.  CPU registers only change when instructions write them, they're thread-private.  CPU registers aren't hardware-managed caches.  C compilers are allowed to do this when there are no synchronization operations like acquire loads, because data races (on non-atomic variables like your array) are undefined behaviour.  MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop

Your C# example doesn't need Thread.MemoryBarrier(); full barriers.  The volatile access already provides release / acquire synchronization like you're doing in C.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

@PeterCordes Thanks for the replies and for helping me better understand these things at a more fundamental level. Firstly, it looks like you are saying that volatile fields will still be cached in the CPU registers but that they just wont be used for data that was marked volatile right? It also seems that you are agreeing with what I said in terms of atomic operations at least for intel while also noting that it depends more on the CPU architecture. Also how exactly does the volatile field protect the array in a way I would not need the memory barrier? I will comment more after I read links.

volatile fields will still be cached in the CPU registers - no, "cached" implies later use of that value instead of re-reading memory the next time you access the variable.  That's one of the things volatile prevents (in both C# and C).  The value will typically get loaded into a register as part of evaluating the expression it's part of, like shared * 2, reloading for each volatile or _Atomic access.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/6E7aejYv8 shows two separate loads for two derefs of an atomic_int *.

C# volatile already implies ordering (unlike C volatile which you shouldn't use for this purpose, use _Atomic.)  C# volatile assignments are release operations, reads are acquire operations, like atomic_load_explicit(p, memory_order_acquire).  This will compile to an asm memory barrier if necessary, or a special instruction, and is a barrier against compile-time reordering.  (But not a full barrier including StoreLoad draining the store buffer; you never need that for acquire/release sync.  https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/)

FYI, it is possible in C# to do a volatile read or write in an array location: var value = Volatile.Read(ref data[i]) and Volatile.Write(ref data[i], value).

I would suggest splitting apart the C and C# versions of this question. Despite the superficial similarities, they are quite different in terms of memory model, and in particular they have completely different semantics for volatile. So trying to discuss both in the same post is likely to lead to confusion. Taking one at a time would be much simpler.

You have some misconceptions:

a Memory Barrier seems to primarily prevent reordering of instructions. This is notable since modern CPU's do something called Speculative Execution which can lead to prematurely running code where if its guess was correct, we would have just of saved some time while if we guessed wrong, we can just roll back the changes. This however could cause problems if multiple threads are modifying data in a time sensitive manner.

Memory Barriers are a compiler thing, preventing the ASM compiler (the JITter in C#) from reordering reads and writes, where it would normally assume the effect is not observable from a single thread. This is separate from a memory fence CPU instruction.
Whether a memory fence instruction needs to be inserted as well is dependent on the CPU architecture, some of which have stronger guarantees than others. Branch prediction is just one of those architecture issues that may or may not be a problem: some CPUs guarantee consistency even with branch prediction.

I assume this code would still work fine with the only issue being the possibility of stale copies being in the CPU registers for a max of a few milliseconds. This would probably be fine if my specific use case had a tolerance of a few milliseconds but how does adding the volatile signal flag fix that exactly?

No, you have a fundamental mistake here: if you don't use volatile then the compiler/JITter is free to keep the data in registers indefinitely. It doesn't have to read from or store into main memory, because the effect is not observable from a single thread. This is the classic mistake of usng while (_someGlobalFlag) { }. You need volatile to avoid this and force read/store to main memory. The CPU then sorts out cache coherency from there, but if it stays in registers then the CPU can't handle that as you haven't told it to.

Thread.MemoryBarrier();  // We need a memory barrier after we write


No, you don't need an explicit memory barrier here, as volatile in C# already provides half-barriers which is enough in this case. You are correct that C doesn't provide barriers.
Again: volatile in and of itself really only refers to forcing a main-memory read/store, and that goes for C. That C# also provides a half-barrier on top is just nice, but in many cases you actually need a full barrier. You need to analyze your code to see what it needs. And MemoryBarrier() by itself does not do what volatile does, it does not guarantee usage of main memory.

Thank you for the reply but I am still confused by the use of volatile when combined with a memory fence in order to protect other code like the array. What I dont understand is why denoting the signal flag as volatile then prevents the data structures within the memory barrier from being cached in the registers. What is the connection here because normally a volatile flag only effects it's self without preventing register caching of other data around it. Secondly, are you stating here that the C# memory barrier works far different from the ASM version? Did my explanation describe the ASM one?

@UnSure: It doesn't prevent the array elements from being loaded into registers.  The point is that they're not loaded until those loads will see the new values, thanks to release/acquire synchronization.  Just like how locking works with a mutex.  If you loop repeatedly over the array, you won't necessarily see any future changes if there isn't any synchronization operation (e.g. C# volatile read of a variable written by the writer thread) between loops.

@UnSure See new edits. volatile and barriers are two different things.

Yeah, I upvoted.  It doesn't say everything that could possibly be said about what the OP wrote (although that could expand to textbook or book-chapter length - my random comments under the question are just scattered thoughts), but it's a good start and makes probably the most important points, that compilers can make asm that reuses old values indefinitely, and that CPU registers are thread-private, an asm equivalent of local variables, not like another level of hardware cache.  Silently making private copies of shared data is the problem that volatile or _Atomic avoid.

Thread.MemoryBarrier(); is also a compiler barriers; it stops the compiler from keeping data in registers.  At least for variables that are potentially shared; an int i loop counter whose address has never been taken (in general, escape analysis) can stay in a register even in a loop that uses a memory barrier.  A release-store by definition involves an actual store in the asm.  If that doesn't happen, it's a buggy / failed attempt at doing a release-store!
